# I am making a text box in python's arcade library. I can't handle the scrolling when the text length increases more than the allowed width

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a text box in python's arcade library. I have the basic hard coded implementation working which is a text box class which stores the keys pressed and displays them in a text box but when the text length is more than box's width it just displays outside of it instead of putting it in the box and scrolling the text left and right using arrow keys.

I have tried to separate the storage of the text and the display of the text in separate classes but since I don't really know how to move cursor around and do basic feature like scrolling can be implemented so it didn't work.

## Text Box Class update Method

```
def update(self, delta_time, keys_pressed):
    if self.text_display.highlighted:
        text, symbol = self.text_storage.update(delta_time, keys_pressed)
        self.text_display.update(delta_time, text, symbol)
```

## Text Storage Class update Method

```
def update(self, delta_time, keys_pressed):
    self.time += delta_time
    self.blink_cursor()
    for key in keys_pressed:
        if key == arcade.key.BACKSPACE:
            self.text = self.text[:-1]
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            if self.cursor_index > 0:
                self.cursor_index -= 1
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            if self.cursor_index < self.char_limit:
                self.cursor_index += 1
        else:
            if len(self.text) < self.char_limit:
                self.text += chr(key)
    return self.text, self.cursor_symbol
```

## Text Display Class update Method

```
def update(self, delta_time, text, symbol):
    self.text = text
    self.symbol = symbol
```

## Text Display Class draw_text Method

```
def draw_text(self):
    if self.highlighted:
        arcade.draw_text(self.text + self.symbol, self.x-self.width/2, 
        self.y, arcade.color.BLACK, font_size=24, anchor_y="center")
    else:
        arcade.draw_text(self.text, self.x-self.width/2, self.y, 
        arcade.color.BLACK, font_size=24, anchor_y="center")
```

I expect it to scroll the text when press the left or right arrow keys or when the text length increases more than the text_box's width but I can't seem to achieve